# Save sql data to localstorage in php

Tags: php

When page load, I have a function return customer data

```
<?php

function customerdata()
{
$sql="select * from Customer";
return exec_to_arry($sql);
} 

?>
```

How to put customerdata to localstorage when page load or rerfresh ?

Answer (score 0):

If by locally you mean in server then you can use `fwrite()` or in session else you can write it inside cookie `setcookie()`

Comment: cookie has small storage , fwrite to create file, I would like to use localstorage to work when offline, I can search offline for quickness. Also It can work for laptop or mobile phone.

Comment: You can write json array to a javascript variable something like 

`<script>$var = '<?php echo json_encode($results); ?>'; </script>`

Comment: Thanks Riz, It worked. I lacked json_encode when I want to get an array.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write data to the localstorage using php because php is a server side programming language and localstorage is a client side storage. There is no way these two can communicate.
If you want to do this, you will need to have some javascript in your html code that saves this data to the localstorage.

You can read more about server side and client side [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171210/153671)